# Redirect Blank Referrers using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, referrer

I want to redirect hits on my page if they do not have a referrer. However, this PHP code below only works if it's on a separate PHP page and not the same as my landing page. This won't work because it needs to be on the page receiving the hits, so if someone visits that page with no referrer, they will be redirected to a false page (yahoo.com).

```
    <?php
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
          header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');
    } else {
          header('Location: http://mypage.com');
    };
    ?>
```

I've tried using Javascript as well, but can't figure out what Javascript considers as a blank referrer.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.referrer == ("undefined" || "null" || "" || "unknown" || "blank" || "false"))
          location.href = "http://yahoo.com";
    </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is your landing page?

Comment: This is one of them currently only has the javascript on the page, http://homesecurity.com-secure.org/lp2/. The working PHP version is at http://homesecurity.com-secure.org/page2.php and you can click here for a quick referrer click test, http://mallygtrk.com/appking/test.php

Comment: you need to make your langing page php, add code above to the very top of it, and configure web server to use this new php page as default one

Comment: How do I configure my server to use the new php page as default? is there a tutorial online? I tried using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as these 'php else redirect' but it did not work.

Comment: http://bignosebird.com/apache/a2.shtml

Comment: I edited my .htaccess file (added `DirectoryIndex index.php`) in the same directory as my landing page and it does not work. You can click here for a referrer test: http://homesecurity.com-secure.org/lp2/ and you can see the continuous redirect error.

Comment: this is correct behavior, when you go to your page from test page - referer is set and not empty - you're going into endless loop, if you just open your page from browser - referer is empty and you go to yahoo

Comment: Why not just use `if(!document.referrer)`